# Desktop resolves hostname of laptop on local network but not vice versa

Tags: networking, ssh

I can ssh to my laptop from my desktop over the wireless network with `ssh thinkpad.local`, but I can't ssh from my laptop to my desktop e.g. `ssh desktop.local`. I have to use the ip address. I thought I had configured both identically. Why won't the laptop resolve the desktop's hostname?

Comment: Please add more information like how you have configured both machine in the question.

Comment: Where does `{desktop,laptop}` get its DNS from? (`cat /etc/resolv.conf` on each). Then read `man resolvconf`

Comment: I added everything in the desktop's resolv.conf to the laptops file and it still wouldn't resolve. Laptop: `nameserver 209.222.18.222  
nameserver 209.222.18.218  
nameserver 192.168.0.1  
nameserver 127.0.1.1` desktop: `nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search austin.rr.com`